# Package Python Project with multiple packages and virtual environment for distribution

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I have a Python project with multiple package (sub) folders. I also have non *.py files in some of these packages (.json, pickle files, etc.). I want to package this along with the virtual environment so that the project can run on a different machine.
Both my current and target computers run Windows.
Answers on SO mentioned pyInstaller, but I do not know if they handle the non *.py files.
What is the easiest way for me to copy my project and the virtual environment to another machine, such that the relative file paths that I have used in my code are preserved?